# High Peak Current Voltage Regulator

Tags: high-current, voltage-reference

I have an ICs which has an operating voltage range from 3.35V up to 4.5V. It typically needs a 20-milliamps current but it can have 1.9-amps current peak. Moreover, my system will work with a battery and I therefore must keep the input voltage as little as possible. I do not know well the field of voltage regulators; I thought of using a classical linear voltage regulator or an LDO, but none of them seems to fit my need. Which kind of voltage regulator would you suggest for the above-mentioned design?

Thanks!

Comment: massive capacitors can supply the current. How long is "peak" current for? This helps you determine how much capacitance you need.

Comment: It is a GSM modules. I am talking about "peak of current consumption through the VCC pads during a GSM 1-slot transmit burst" which shoud be used "to dimension maximum current capability of power supply" (quoted from the [page 22 of DS](http://www.u-blox.com/images/downloads/Product_Docs/SARA-G3_DataSheet_%28UBX-13000993%29.pdf)).

Comment: it's very common for GSM modules, for example the Arduino GSM modem shield, to have a large tantalum or similar capacitor to handle the pulsed current

Comment: Yes. But wouldn't it be safer to have a voltage regulator furnishing the right current ?

Comment: no, it's completely unnecessary. continuous current is nowhere near the same as pulsed/peak current.

Comment: "If the module is transmitting in 2G single - slot mode (as in GSM talk mode ) in the 850 or 900 MHz bands, at the maximum RF power control level (approximately 2 W or 33 dBm in the Tx slot/burst) , the current consumption can reach an high peak / pulse (see SARA-G3 series Data Sheet) for 576.9 µs (width of t he transmit slot/burst) with a periodicity of 4.615 ms (width of 1 frame = 8 slots/burst), so with a 1/8 duty cycle according to GSM TDMA (Time Division Multiple Access)." [Source, p.21](http://www.u-blox.com/images/downloads/Product_Docs/SARA-G3-U2_SysIntegrManual_%28UBX-13000995%29.pdf)

Comment: Then, I use `Q=CV` and `I=dQ/dt` to determine the capacitance needed ?

Comment: Well, the Arduino guys think that 100uF in a huge-ass surface mount capacitor is good enough, so you can try the same. If you wanted to work it out, i'd simulate a simple switched 1.9A load for the durations given and play with capacitor values until you find a match for good enough performance (not too much voltage drop, you dont want to drop more than 200-300mV on the power rail during the pulse

Answer (score 1):

You don't say exactly which GSM module you're using, but I used an idea (similar to that described by KyranF in the comments to your question) a few years ago with a GSM module when I had to deal with a very similar situation.

Similar to you I had to allow the module to draw bursts of current in the 1.5A to 2A range for short infrequent periods.

My module also had a fairly wide supply voltage range because it has its own internal voltage regulators, so I could tolerate a larger voltage droop over the course of the current pulse than would normally be acceptable - providing the voltage started off near the top of the module's acceptable range at the beginning of the pulse.

I experimented a bit with component values, and in the end settled on 3x470uF electrolytics in parallel and a 2.2ohm series resistor from my 5V 500mA supply.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxZw8X.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Of course in your case you'll have to use a 4.5V supply since that's the maximum your module is rated for.